Error Dotnet Entity Framework Add with ValueOnGeneratedAdd
I have a problem when I try to add in my database a Relative_Strength_Index Data, the entity framework dosn't complete the sql request and crash, I have the same configurations for ma Company model and it's working so i don't know why :
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (211ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = UInt32), @p1='?' (DbType = Single)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      **INSERT INTO `relative_strength_index` (`id_timeframe`, `relative_strength_value`)
      VALUES (@p0, @p1);
      SELECT `id_relative_strength_index`
      FROM `relative_strength_index`
      WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND ;**
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'ProbabilityX_API.Settings.ProbabilityXContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

My files :
RelativeStrengthIndexConfiguration.cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ProbabilityX_API.Models;

namespace ProbabilityX_API.Configurations
{
    public static class RelativeStrengthIndexConfiguration
    {
        public static void SetRelativeStrengthIndex(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<RelativeStrengthIndexModel>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("relative_strength_index");

                entity.Property(x => x.IdRelativeStrengthIndex)
                    .HasColumnName("id_relative_strength_index")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("INT UNSIGNED")
                    .IsRequired();

                entity.Property(x => x.RelativeStrengthValue)
                    .HasColumnName("relative_strength_value")
                    .HasColumnType("FLOAT")
                    .IsRequired();

                entity.Property(x => x.IdTimeframe)
                    .HasColumnName("id_timeframe")
                    .HasColumnType("INT UNSIGNED")
                    .IsRequired();

                // Définition de la clé primaire
                entity.HasKey(x => x.IdRelativeStrengthIndex);

                // Définition de la relation avec TimeframeModel
                entity.HasOne<TimeframeModel>(x => x.Timeframe)
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(x => x.IdTimeframe);
            });
        }
    }
}

RelativeStrengthModel.cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ProbabilityX_API.Models
{
    public class RelativeStrengthIndexModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdRelativeStrengthIndex { get; set; }
        public float RelativeStrengthValue { get; set; }
        public int IdTimeframe { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdTimeframe")]
        public TimeframeModel? Timeframe { get; set; }

    }

}

RelativeStrengthRepository.cs
The function who dosn't work ...
public async Task<RelativeStrengthIndexModel> AddRelativeStrengthIndex(RelativeStrengthIndexModel value)
{
    _context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
    _context.RelativeStrengthIndexes.Add(value);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return value;
}

My database Configuration
The data I send
For the debugging test i have done :
I have the CompanyConfiguration who work and seems to be the exact same code :
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ProbabilityX_API.Models;

namespace ProbabilityX_API.Configurations
{
    public static class CompanyConfiguration
    {
        public static void SetCompany(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyModel>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("company");

                entity.Property(x => x.IdCompany)
                    .HasColumnName("id_company")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("INT UNSIGNED")
                    .IsRequired();

                entity.Property(x => x.NameCompany)
                    .HasColumnName("name_company")
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .IsRequired();

                entity.Property(x => x.IdTypeStock)
                    .HasColumnName("id_type_stock")
                    .HasColumnType("INT UNSIGNED")
                    .IsRequired();

                // Définition de la clé primaire
                entity.HasKey(x => x.IdCompany);

                // Définition de la relation avec TypeStockModel
                entity.HasOne<TypeStockModel>(x => x.TypeStock)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(x => x.IdTypeStock)
                    .HasPrincipalKey(r => r.IdTypeStock);

            });
        }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ProbabilityX_API.Models
{
    public class CompanyModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdCompany { get; set; }
        public string NameCompany { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int IdTypeStock { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdTypeStock")]
        public TypeStockModel? TypeStock { get; set; }
    }
}

public async Task<CompanyModel> AddCompany(CompanyModel company)
{
    _context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
    _context.Companies.Add(company);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return company;
}

Data i send
The normal add entity framework function :
Info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (38ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = UInt32), @p1='?' (Size = 255)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      **INSERT INTO `company` (`id_type_stock`, `name_company`)
      VALUES (@p0, @p1);
      SELECT `id_company`
      FROM `company`
      WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND `id_company` = LAST_INSERT_ID();**

And I have try to switch database, rename column name (if it was too long) , delete all foreign key and foreign key column

Yoir database is mariadb, not mysql. Check the error message...
